# Repeating a SVG path

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Say that I have the following arrow, which I want to repeat several times at different locations within the svg:

```
<svg width="400" height="400">
<path transform="translate(150,100)" fill="black" d="M 0.5,0.5 l-100,0 -25,20 25,20 100,0 z" />
<path transform="translate(300,200)" fill="black" d="M 0.5,0.5 l-100,0 -25,20 25,20 100,0 z" />
<path transform="translate(150,300)" fill="black" d="M 0.5,0.5 l-100,0 -25,20 25,20 100,0 z" />
</svg>
```

[image: arrows]

I might want to change the path shape in the future, so I would prefer to avoid copy-pasting the `d` attribute all over the place.

Is it possible to define path's shape somewhere and then place it at different `x`, `y` coordinates, without manipulating it from javascript?

Two thoughts:

- `d` is an attribute, not a property, so we cannot use CSS AFAIK
- `<defs>` does [not seem to support paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs)

Is there any way to avoid copy past the entire thing, short of injecting it from javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer provided as an extension to JCD's answer in order to show OP what I by the `<symbol>` not being required here.  `<symbol>` elements provide some features that are not needed when you are simply reusing an element.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <defs>
    <path id="mypath" fill="black" d="M 0,20 l25,20 100,0 0,-40 -100,0 z" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#mypath" x="50" y="100" />
  <use xlink:href="#mypath" x="200" y="200" />
  <use xlink:href="#mypath" x="50" y="300" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Just one thing: I want to stylize it using CSS for such effects as mouse hover. I seem to be able to do it if I do `<use class="arrow">` and then `arrow hover { fill: red }` for instance. But could I maybe stylize the `<defs><path>` directly? (I seem unable to.)

Comment: Your rules as stated won't work. Did you mean `.arrow:hover {}`?  You can style the `<path>` directly (as long as you remove the `fill="black"`) but you can't do a `:hover` rule on it because when referenced via a `<use>` it does not appear in the DOM tree, and it can't be styled individually. By that I mean separately from the other instances.

Comment: Yes, I meant `.arrow`...! Okay, I understand now what is going on... Thanks!

Comment: I think you should really accept JCDs answer.  He provided the main solution for your question.  I was just clarifying some points.

Answer (score 7):

`<defs>` does in fact support `<path>`, since it is a "Shape Element" as listed under the "Permitted Content" section of the documentation. However, `<defs>` by itself doesn't do much, it's just a semantic way to organize your SVG. What you're looking for are `<symbol>` and `<use>`.

`<symbol>` defines a template that you can use and re-use.

`<use>` creates an instance of a given symbol.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="mypath">
      <path fill="black" d="M 0,20 l25,20 100,0 0,-40 -100,0 z" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#mypath" x="50" y="100" />
  <use xlink:href="#mypath" x="200" y="200" />
  <use xlink:href="#mypath" x="50" y="300" />
</svg>
```

Your `<path>` data is kind of weird because it starts on the left side of the element and then proceeds to draw even further to the left, necessitating the `transform` property. Note how I do it in the above snippet (starting the line at the left edge of the element and never drawing further left than that) which works a bit better and doesn't need `transform` to avoid accidental cropping.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol

Comment: A symbol is unnecessary here.  You can just put your path in the `<defs>` section and reference that directly.

Comment: The reason why my arrow path goes right-to-left is a historical artifact from the fact that I am still learning SVG. I wanted to flip the arrow and, at the time, I did not know about `transform=scale(1,-1)` hehe.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau, could you please clarify with an example (maybe by editing this answer)? If there is another way, possibly simpler, it would be great to post it.

Comment: I provided an additional answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Thank you all for guiding me through! I really appreciate it! I am marking the other answer because it is more complete, but I am giving you a bounty (or will as soon as I can) as a token of my appreciation.

Comment: @RicardoCruz thanks for the bounty, glad I could help :)